# Cannot install database engine services, replication and SQL writer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, sql-server-express

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express, but I get this error (I try to uninstall and delete registry key, try to change account for database engine to NT Authority\System, but reinstall still not working):

#### Feature failure reason:

> An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.

#### Error details:

> Error installing SQL Server Writer Component
>   The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with the package. The error code is 29559.
>   Error code: 29559
>   Log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160310_225904\SqlWriter_Cpu32_1.log

Here is the summary of setup bootstrap:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068024457
  Start time:                    2016-03-10 23:00:02
  End time:                      2016-03-10 23:03:10
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for Writer:          Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  NHAT-PC
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Future Windows Version
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x86
  Process architecture:          32 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Express Edition      11.2.5058.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Express Edition      11.2.5058.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Client Tools Connectivity                1033                 Express Edition      11.2.5058.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                 Express Edition      11.2.5058.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Client Tools SDK                         1033                 Express Edition      11.2.5058.0     No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  Installation location:         E:\1885bc8762c587e3d8\x86\setup\
  Installation edition:          Express

  Slipstream:                    True
  SP Level                       2

Product Update Status:
  Success: KB 2958429

Product Updates Selected for Installation:
  Title:                         Service Pack 2
  Knowledge Based Article:       KB 2958429
  Version:                       11.2.5058.0
  Architecture:                  x86
  Language:                      1033

  Update Source:                 Slipstream


User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    true
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           <empty>
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    DQN
  INSTANCENAME:                  DQN
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           NHAT-PC\nhat
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  Slipstream
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160310_225904\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Writer Component
  Component error code:          29559
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160310_225904\SqlWriter_Cpu32_1.log
  Error description:             The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with the package. The error code is 29559.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.5058.0&EvtType=SqlWriter.msi%40Do_sqlServiceSidType_32%4029559

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Writer Component
  Component error code:          29559
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160310_225904\SqlWriter_Cpu32_1.log
  Error description:             The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with the package. The error code is 29559.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.5058.0&EvtType=SqlWriter.msi%40Do_sqlServiceSidType_32%4029559

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Writer Component
  Component error code:          29559
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160310_225904\SqlWriter_Cpu32_1.log
  Error description:             The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with the package. The error code is 29559.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.5058.0&EvtType=SqlWriter.msi%40Do_sqlServiceSidType_32%4029559

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160310_225904\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

My machine is Windows 10 x86, and has only 2GB of RAM.

The contents of the setup log file *SqlWriter_Cpu32_1.log* is [available here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=33088F05373FF3C3!3697&authkey=!APtAK__e7QVsNRw&ithint=file%2Clog) (hosted on OneDrive).

Comment: Right, I get that you might have installed an x86 version of Windows, but WHY? Is the underlying hardware really x86?

Comment: @AaronBertrand : I think my computer has only 2gb of ram then I decided to install windows 32bit , how can i check if the underlying hardware is really x86 or not like you said ?

Comment: Did you buy it after, oh, 2002? [Check here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001121.htm). Why does it only have 2 GB of RAM? You're going to spend hours trying to optimize this system so you can get anything at all done on it when you could go buy probably $50 or $60 worth of memory to have 16 GB and be in a much better place to install x64 (and do just about anything, frankly - most phones have more than 2 GB of RAM today).

Answer (score 2):

Solved this:  I had an old SQL Server on the same machine.  When I removed the old one, I deleted all the folders and ran ccleaner to clean the registry.  This left a damaged sqlwriter service on the machine.  I used "sc delete sqlwriter" to remove it.  Once I did that, it ran ok.  Another thing that I think helped was running sql server installer as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

From the logs you posted we have

> Configuring service:
>         Name: SQLWriter   SID type: 0x1 Failed:   Unable to set the SID type for service SQLWriter to 1. **Error code: 2.**
>
> Error description:             The installer has encountered an
>   unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem
>   with the package. The error code is 29559.

The [error code 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) here means that `system cannot find the file specified`. This is also what the other message is saying. When you get such message it can be possibly because of two things the package you downloaded is corrupt and some files are missing or the account running the installation does not have privilege to access the file. I believe the file it was looking for is `C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSIEC4A.tmp` because of following

> MSI (s) (E4:F4) [23:02:57:785]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
>   **C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSIEC4A.tmp**, Entrypoint: Do_sqlServiceSidType
>    Function=Do_sqlServiceSidType   Doing Action: Do_sqlServiceSidType PerfTime Start:
>   Do_sqlServiceSidType : Thu Mar 10 23:02:57 2016  Configuring service:
>         Name: SQLWriter   SID type: 0x1 
>   Failed: Unable to set the SID type for service SQLWriter to 1. Error
>   code: 2.

so I assume the lookup was for above DLL and it was not found.

What additionally you can do is

1. Download SQL Server 2012 express setup again
2. Make sure you meed all [Hardware and Software requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) specially related to .net framework. I strongly suggest you to read the article before you again proceed with installation
3. Make sure you always right click on `setup.exe` file and select `run as administrator.`
4. Make sure account you are using to run installation has full permission on system drive C:\Windows\

When you begin installation 2nd time dont install SQL Server client tools they are already installed.

**NOTE:** This is low level troubleshooting a more detailed and accurate information can be provided by MS engineer.

Comment: when  I run the setup, it tell me these : 
Already Installed :
  + Window PowerShell 2.0
  + MS .Net Framework 3.5
  + MS Visual Studio 2010 Redistributables
  + MS .Net Framework 4.0, 
To be installed from media :
  + MS Visual Studio 2010 Shell . 

I try to install several times but have the same error .
I use SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU to install

Comment: Please uninstall previous installation and try

Comment: I uninstall all including share features by remove function of sql server 2012 and reinstall but still have same error. Is there something wrong because I installed VS 2013 Ultimate first and then install sql server 2012 ?

Comment: Yes that can be but I don't have anything to corroborate the fact but I suggest you uninstall VS 2013, I am saying so because VS2013 has SSDT which is the one which might be causing the issue. Other thing I hope you downloaded the express 2012 package again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is going to sound a little crazy, but if you are installing from a mounted ISO, extracting the ISO out to disk, as recommended on this [Error Installing SQL Server 2012 Management Tools MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a90b732-8bee-4891-a49c-eada5d18b00e/error-installing-sql-server-2012-management-tools?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade), cleared up the error for me. I used 7-Zip to extract it (the thread suggests that it won't work if you use WinZIP to extract it).